# what industry recommends to keep child class object into superclass referance variable?

Tags: java

Why would we use a polymorphic approach when creating an object, for example `List l=new Arraylist();`? When should I prefer to assign it to the child class rather than the parent, for example, `ArrayList al=new ArrayList()`, and when should I use the parent class, `List l= new ArrayList()`?